# (why) is the probability or marginal likelihood of data proportional to dimension?

Tags: probability, self-study, likelihood

In the paper [A Note on the evaluation of generative models](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.01844)
section 3.2 has the statements

> Assume $p$ is the density of a model for $d$ dimensional data $x$
>   ...
>   For high-dimensional data, $\log p(x)$ will be proportional to $d$.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general, check for example when $p$ is the multivariate uniform density on $[0,1]^d$.

In the article, there are some assumptions of normality. You can check the article given for reference, especially the discussion in Section 5 for details: https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/7028865/file/7028866